# Function to check multiple possible fields

Tags: javascript, dom, submit, field

I'm making a question and answer application.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/4YTA6/

How can I expand this to allow more than one questions of the same type?

I don't know to let the function know witch field to check.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I want to check each answer indiviually.
Would this require a new form for each question?

Comment: FYI, `id` attributes may not legally start with a number.

Comment: When you're adding more questions, are they going to be this same "add an apostrophe" question, or different questions altogether? Also, do you just want the questions defined within the JavaScript as an array and then build up the HTML magically from there, or simply have some JavaScript validate questions in the HTML based off of... hidden form fields? Just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: More of the same format.
I would be okay with making an array, 
I was just typing this up to try it out.

My real problem is about getting the function to validate the fields one at a time, when needed, not all at once or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technically works but could probably use quite a bit of cleanup -- constructive criticism welcomed. (Make the HTML file actually valid, don't link directly to jQuery, clean up my jQuery, etc etc.  I'm not a jQuery expert yet.)  I went the route where the JavaScript looks at all the appropriate HTML and displays responses (instead of building HTML based off of JavaScript arrays.)

You can basically copy-paste the `<li>...</li>` stuff and change the number following `q-` and `a-` for each question and it will work.

Ideally, we'd be using server-side programming to verify answers (since the client can easily view the answers.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform" id="myform">
        <p>Make each of the following possessive by adding the appropriate apostrophe where needed. </p>
        <ol type="1">
            <li>boys: 
                <input type="text" name="q-1" /><!-- field for user input -->
                <input type="hidden" name="a-1" value="boy's" /><!-- answer -->
            </li>
            <li>girls: 
                <input type="text" name="q-2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="a-2" value="girl's" />
            </li>
        </ol>
        <p><input type="button" id="validate-btn" value="Check" /></p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready( function() {
            $('#validate-btn').click( function() {
                $(this).css('display','none');
                $('[name|="q"]').each( function() {
                    // find the associated answer
                    var pattern = /q\-([0-9]+)/;    // regular expression to pull question/answer number from field name
                    var result = pattern.exec($(this).attr('name'))[1]; // get the question/answer number
                    // you could probably just navigate around with DOM to get the next hidden text field instead, eh.
                    // get reference to the input with the answer
                    var answerbox = $('[name="a-'+result+'"]');
                    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
                    // verify answer, display replacement text
                    if($(this).val() == answerbox.val()) {
                        $(this).replaceWith('&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>Correct!</strong>');
                    } else {
                        $(this).replaceWith('&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>Incorrect! The answer was "'+ answerbox.val() +'"</strong>');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not like this would check each problem individually.
I don't completely understand your answer, but I'm playing around with it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need a new `<input>` element for each question you want the user to answer.

Comment: I don't know what to change in my function to allow for more questions though.